# What is "value of object index" in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, terminology

It is written in documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), that if a function passed as `by` parameter to `groupby` function, then

> it’s called on each value of the object’s index

What does `value of the object’s index` mean here? Will this function receive all values of each column for each row?

Answer (score 1):

This means that for a function `f`, `groupby` will run `f(df.index[0])`, `f(df.index[1])`, etc.

Here is an example of use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': list('ABCDEF')})
#   col
# 0   A
# 1   B
# 2   C
# 3   D
# 4   E
# 5   F

out = df.groupby(lambda x: x%2).agg(''.join)
#    col
# 0  ACE
# 1  BDF
```

Another one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': list('ABCDEF')},
                  index=['x', 'X', 'y', 'z', 'Y', 'Z'])
#   col
# x   A
# X   B
# y   C
# z   D
# Y   E
# Z   F

out = df.groupby(str.upper).agg(''.join)
#   col
# X  AB
# Y  CE
# Z  DF
```

Comment: in short `.groupby(func)` means `.groupby([func(i) for i in df.index])`.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks, that's a simple way to explain it!